# git broken pipe when staging changes to repository

Tags: git

This error occurs when I try to stage the changes to a currently empty repo:

```
error writing "file2e7f660": broken pipe
error writing "file2e7f660": broken pipe
    while executing
"puts -nonewline $fd "[encoding convertto utf-8 $path]\0""
    (procedure "write_update_index" line 34)
    invoked from within
"write_update_index file2e7f660 {public/Aanmeegamalar/desktop.ini public/google10c909b6a3b8.html public/hehe.txt public/..."
```

I used the Git GUI for this job because when I use git bash, it only adds a single file even if i add the directory `git add public`. What could resolve this? I googled for answers but `git config http.postBuffer 209715200` didn't solve the problem.

EDIT: I also tried reinstalling git but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

EDIT 2: Operating system is windows 7 32bit.

Comment: Which "git gui" did you use? It seems to have corrupt something in the index.

Comment: `git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1`

Comment: Try being more explicit so we can reproduce the error you are seeing. It sounds like "mkdir z && mkdir z\public && cd z && echo a>file && echo b>public\file && git init && git gui" should create the conditions for the error when we stage the files. However, they stage fine when I try this.

Comment: It is also worth calling it as 'git gui --trace'. If you then hit Ctrl-F2 it will show the Tk console and you can see all the git commands that were actually called. Presumably 'git update-index' is returning an error for some reason and it is not being handled well.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by staging the files a few at a time, directory by directory, instead of trying to stage all 200+ at once.

I encountered this error while trying to stage about 200 file changes following a big directory clean-up.

I wasn't able to solve this by running as administrator.
I wasn't able to solve this by checking read permissions on the files.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question but I just came across this myself. In my case one of the files I was attempting to stage was locked. I got the *broken pipe* message in Git GUI but when I tried a `git add` from a windows cmd line I got a *permission denied* message that told me which file was the issue.

Comment: This actually helped me just now. I closed Visual Studio and ran the 'Stage Changed' and it worked with 552 files.

Answer (score 1):

easy to solve.
You are see this error because not have rights to write in folder.

When you are attempting to create new repo of your folder - try to create it in the place, which you are owner and have a full rights to write.

If you are already trying to push and get this error - delete .git folder, set rights to write in this folder and create repo again. Be sure, that you are can see a hidden files in the folders.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on this error, was for some reason in Microsoft, even though I am the Administrator, and have administrator rights, (different username than Administrator), I still did not have full rights to all folders, ???

So I had to add me to the security of folders I use with Git-Gui. After I did that, I made sure that i started Git-Gui as an Administrator, and voila, it worked!

This is of course on a Windows box. As for Linux, it would be similar as well...

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Actually, i believe that it was not so much changing privileges as it was simply running git-GUI 'as Administrator'. I say this because I had to work with this error again in another repository, and I forgot to run as Administrator. I'm creating a link which will automatically 'run as Administrator'....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I had to need stages my different projects in Git GUI.
The solution : close all programs which use these files can stage projects in Git UI.

Windows 10 1909,
Git 2.25.1

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents in addition to Sergio answer which worked for my case with slight adjustment:

I wanted to create common repository for metatrader5 files which are located in system somewhere like C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\terminal_hash\MQL5 and it's protected by user 'system' which setup read-only rights to that folder even if you will change rights and save changes.

So, I removed inheritance of that MQL5 folder (future git repo) and remove all other users with full access except owner - user with admin right under what I was working. And after remove and reinit git there it works fine.